# how to create a database other than admin in cosmos db?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I recently created an cosmosdb account which uses Mongo API. when I create new collections the only database it uses is "admin".

I tried attaching the db name like testdb to the url but that didn't work.
I tried mongo shell to create a db but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create your database ahead of time (using either the portal or the Azure SDK), or create via MongoDB.

Not sure how you tried attaching to `testdb` but from the shell, you should be able to execute:

`use testdb`

Once you do this, you can execute something like

`db.newcollection.save({foo:"bar"})`

This will result in a new collection created, within `testdb`. You can see this via `show dbs`:

```
globaldb:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin          0.000GB
testdb         0.000GB
```

Note: When you create a collection implicitly this way (vs creating explicitly via either the portal or the Cosmos DB SDK), you will get a default RU setting for the collection (1000 RU currently), and would need to adjust accordingly via the portal afterward to suit your needs.

Comment: How can I access this using the url should I just use the /{database} like in any mongodb instance.

Comment: That's correct. Just specify whatever database you want, on the commandline, with `/<dbname>`. Then, when you create your new collection, it will be created in that database (and if the database doesn't exist yet, it will be created when you go to save a doc in your new collection).

Comment: the problem was that database doesn't show up when using the show dbs; command if u don't create a collection. got it.